# Running more than spark streaming job in Google dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-structured-streaming

How do I run more than one spark streaming job in dataproc cluster? I created multiple queues using `capacity-scheduler.xml` but now I will need 12 queues if I want to run 12 different streaming - aggregate applications. Any idea?

Comment: got any solution??

Answer (score 0):

Dataproc 1.2 image enabled fair mode in capacity scheduler which should do what you want without overhead of queues [1] [2].

[1] https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/flexible_scheduling_policies.html

[2] https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/19342/yarn-fair-sharing-ordering-policy-for-capacity-sch.html